# how video recording only landscape in default camera in titanium in iPhone?

Tags: ios, module, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am developing an iOS application in Titanium Appcelerator and using inbuilt camera to video recording for 1-2 minutes but video recording only in landscape not in portrait mode.How its possible,i have open the camera its always open in portrait mode.
How is possible video recording only in landscape mode and camera open only landscape mode.
So your suggestions are valuable , so kindly let me know what is the best way forward.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Kindly explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: How is possible video recording only in landscape mode and camera open only landscape mode using default camera in iOS in titanium

Comment: The question here is the same problem that I´m having. UIImagePickerController opens in portrait mode. After the recording is done, surprisingly, the video is in landscape mode... It rotates... and I don´t know why.. I think this is what our friend asked... Please, help him... and me as well...